# split string in js and ask if based on specific letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to do an if-statement based on the `alt` text of various image tags.
So my markup is like:

```
<img src="image1.png" alt="1 vote, average: 3.00 out of 5">
<img src="image2.png" alt="3 votes, average: 4.00 out of 5">
<img src="image3.png" alt="5 votes, average: 5.00 out of 5">
```

and what I would like to do is get the number after `average:` so `X.00`.

So something like:

```
 $("img").each(function(){
    if ($('img').attr('alt') /* .dofunctiontosplitthestring(); */ == '5.00')
    {
      // do something
    }
 });
```

The `alt` of the image will be always the same except that `vote` and `votes` varies. So it must be possible in JS to split the string after `'average:'` to isolate the number and do the if statement based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your number is always going to have 2 decimal places you could do something like this:

```
$("img").each(function(){
    var altParts = $(this).attr('alt').split(': ');
    var average = '';

    if (altParts.length == 2) {
        average = altParts[1].substr(0,4);
    }
    if (average == '5.00')
    {
      alert($(this).attr('src'));
    }
 });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ze68/)

Comment: yep thats it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Get the parts from `average` to `number` and split the number from that part something like,

```
var data = $('img').attr('alt');

var pattern = /average\:\s*\d+\.0{2}/; //getting parts 'average: 3.00'
var matchPatt = data.match(pattern)[0]; 
var resArr =  matchPatt.split(":"); // splitting into array [average, 3.00]
var number = resArr[1] // number is 3.00
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/whHwZ/)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this all with regex and parseFloat.

```
var stringValue = $('img').attr('alt');
var value = parseFloat(stringValue.replace(/^.*average: (.*) out.*$/, '$1'), 10);

// do what you need with value
```

An alternative method is to do a regex match

```
if ($('img').attr('alt').match(/ 5\.00 /) != null) {
  // do stuff
}
```

A third alternative is to use the regex test method

```
var search = / 5\.00 /;
if ( search.test($('img').attr('alt')) ) {
  // do stuff
}
```